# How to use I18n.locale with Hash#dig

Tags: ruby, hash, rails-i18n

I have the following Hash:

```
h = {
      forms: {
        version1: {
          href: { 
            en: 'https://form1_en.example.org',
            de: 'https://form1_de.example.org'
          }
        },
        version2: {
          href: {
            en: 'https://form2_en.example.org',
            de: 'https://form2_de.example.org'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am trying to access verion1 href for the user's current locale. So what I do is:

```
Proj.config.forms.dig('version1', 'href', I18n.locale)
```

However, this results in *nil* even though *I18n.locale* returns en.

This, however, works perfectly fine and returns the correct href.

```
Proj.config.forms.dig('version1', 'href', 'en')
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can I not use *I18n.locale* in connection with hash#dig?

Comment: I edited the presentation of the hash in your example to make it a valid Ruby object. Doing so makes its structure more clear and avoids the need for each reader who wishes to cut and paste your code to do what I did: convert it into a valid Rufy object. I also assigned a variable (`h`) to the hash, allowing readers to refer to the hash in comments and answers as simply `h`, without having to define it. I suggest that whenever you give an example you ensure all inputs are valid objects and assign a variable to each. You could of course use a different format for writing the hash.

Comment: Just a comment about the use of [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (and its close cousins [Array#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [Struct#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html#method-i-dig), all of which made their debut in Ruby v2.3.). This method is for use where a key of a nested hash may or may not be present. For example, instead `h.key?(:a) && h[:a].key?(:b) && h[:a][:b].key?(:c) ? h[:a][:b][:c] : nil`, it allowed one to write `h.dig(:a,:b,:c)`. `dig` should *not* be used, however, when...

Comment: ...all the keys in the chain should be present. In the above example, suppose `h` should have a key `:a`, `h[:a]` should have a key `:b`, `h[:a][:b]` should have a key `:c` and `h = {a: {t: {c: 'cat'}}}`, meaning that we have a bug in our code (because `h[:a]` does not have a key `:b`). Then `x = h.dig(:a,:b,:c) #=> nil`. You might raise an exception if `x` is not `nil`, in which case you have to track down the bug. If you don't test if `x` is not `nil` the bug will be buried more deeply. On the other hand, suppose `h[:a][:b][:c] #=> nil` were valid when all the nested keys were present?...

Comment: ...That would present a potentially nasty problem. By contrast,`h[:a][:b][:c] #=> NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)`, which is *exactly what we want*. We still have to find the bug, but no extra code is needed to indicate that we have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that possible problem might be if `I18n.locale` returns `:en` instead of `'en'`. In this case you can solve it in a few ways:

```rb
Proj.config.forms.dig('version1', 'href', I18n.locale.to_s)
```

or

```rb
Proj.config.forms.with_indifferent_access.dig('version1', 'href', I18n.locale)
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick response! That works perfectly fine. Will mark this as correct answer as soon as I am able to :)